# Win 10 after April update no longer detects Microphone on line-in

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, headset, windows-10-v1803

just got the big April update on my laptop (AlienWare), and line-in headsets no longer work.
I tried

1. Bose QuietComfort 25
2. Samsung EHS64 Stereo Headset
3. Condenser Microphone, SF-666, not a headset, but I tested, for Science!

When I run troubleshooting on 'Input Devices' and select 'Line In', I get told that the microphone or headset is unplugged. This is simply wrong, both headsets worked fine up to the minute that I had to restart my machine because of the update.

I have tried

1. Update the Realtech driver, and reboot -> Nothing
2. Remove the Realtech driver, and reboot -> Nothing (though driver did get re-installed)
3. Checked the privacy settings per [windowscentral.com](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-april-2018-update-common-problems-and-fixes#fix_microphone_problem_windows10_1803) -> Everything was fine (I can use the laptop microphone fine, but that's a crappy microphone)
4. Checked [Google hit 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeCh7aCAfYg), but my 'Line In' is active, it just does not detect that I plugged in
   [image]
5. Used a USB headset, this works fine
6. Remove the Realtech driver (checking 'delete'), and reboot -> Nothing (though driver did get re-installed)
7. Checked with the "AlienWare Update" tool, everything is up to date.
8. Removed every single audio driver (checking 'delete'), and reboot -> Nothing (though most drivers got re-installed)

To be sure, yes, I do click on Headset (with Microphone) when I plug my headset.
[image]

Comment: Did you go into settings and privacy and allow your app to access the microphone?

Comment: Yes, that is under 'I tried' , item 3

Comment: In PC Settings, Privacy, Microphone, verify that are set to On: “Allow apps to access your microphone” and "Allow access to the Microphone on this Device". As you have Alienware, check if Support Assist has some driver updates such as a new BIOS. As last resort, try in Device Manger to uninstall all audio related devices while checking "Uninstall software" and reboot, but first ensure you can reinstall the drivers.

Comment: Try installing realtek drivers 2.81 instead of 2.82.  Had to do that for another user.

Comment: We've seen this issue with 1709 on several computer models. In our experience it was nearly always the drivers.

Comment: @cybernard My driver version is 6.0.1.8098?

Comment: @harrymc That all checked. I can by the way use my USB headset with microphone perfectly. It's not a privacy issue.

Comment: Your USB headset wouldn't be using your audio device.  You need to try using a different driver.

Comment: @Ramhound I upgraded the driver, removed and re-installed the driver, what else can I do? I only mention my USB headset just to 'prove' that it's not a privacy issue.

Comment: You indicated the driver got "reinstalled" are you manually selecting a different driver after that happens?

Comment: @Ramhound No, this happens manually.

Comment: @tomdemuyt - So are you manually selecting a different version of the driver then what was already installed?

Comment: @Ramhound No, I misspoke, it happens automatically. There is no point in time where I can choose  a version.

Comment: You need to use Device Manager and manual select the driver that was suggested in a previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78530/discussion-between-ramhound-and-tomdemuyt).